# How to enable google cloud storge bucket alerts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to enable google cloud storage buckets alerts on following items

alerts to capture extraordinary growth

upper limit threshold and key off an alert if that limit is reached.

daily growth of objects

number of object and if any GCP limitations to trigger an alert how to enable this

number of requests per bucket

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new alerting policy pointing to the GCS bucket resource.

On the console go to **Monitoring->Alerting CREATE POLICY**, in the **What do you want to track?** section click on **ADD CONDITION**, select the gcs_bucket resource in the dropdown menu for **Resource type**, and in the **Select a metric** dropdown you can select the particular metric to track.

To catch any abrupt growing of a particular bucket, you can use the metric **Total bytes** with the Condition "Increases by" and the percentage that you want to set up as a threshold to trigger the alert.

For the upper limit, you can use the same metric as before but with the Condition "is above" and the total Bytes as threshold.

For the number of objects use the metric **Object count**.

For the number of requests use the metric **Request count**.

For daily growth, I cannot think of a particular way to measure that exact metric, but you could create a policy to track the total bytes with a period of 1 day and you will get a graphic where you can easily see the daily change.